# Cloth Sim not Rendering

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation

I'm working on a cloth simulated shirt, and for a while I had it working. However, whenever I render it, the cloth does nothing, it stays floating in the air.

I've searched for answers on this, I tried deleting double vertices, making the subdivision modifier's viewport and render levels the same, but nothing works.
I made sure the cloth sim modifier has the rendering enabled, I'm not in edit mode, I feel like I've tried just about everything.

I have the render and .blend files attached here:
[image]

[image: Screenshot of render (it's just this for the whole video)]

Comment: have you baked your simulation ?

Comment: I've tried but that doesn't seem to help the render.

Comment: yeah the bake is just the shirt mesh floating

Comment: You mentioned you had it working, is it supposed to work in your blend file?

Comment: no, the blend file is what I have now.

Comment: if I had a working blend file, I would have just used that instead of asking the question.

Comment: No need to be abrasive, we're trying to help here. The way you phrased your post made me think you had something functional in viewport but not in render.

Comment: sorry about that, I'm just a little frustrated.

Comment: The problem is probably a few "duplicated" vertices (or better vertices that are too close together). If you do a Merge By Distance with `0.001 m` then 3 vertices will be removed and the simulation will work again. I also would apply the Mirror modifier, plus Scale & Rotation as noted in the answer below.

Comment: Yes! this fixed it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The sewing process of the cloth simulation needs Self Collisions to work. Without it, the simulation basically can't make the vertices of the cloth interact with each other, they can only interact with other objects with collisions enabled.

Start by enabling Self Collisions here:

[image]

You should already have a functional simulation just with that. All that's left to do is playing with the parameters to get the look you want. I'm not an expert in that, so I'll leave it there.

---

On another note, a few advices to avoid issues down the line:

You model is over 2 meters high, it's quite tall for a human being. Just to give you an idea, this is a cube of 1.73m height and 43cm large/wide, which is an average human dimension:

[image]

Since you are doing physics simulations, measures matter. You are not too far out of scale, so it might not be that troublesome to keep it like this, but I advise you to scale that character down.

I'd advise applying the mirror modifier as well as the Rotation and Scale via <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Scale to avoid further issues.

Also consider lightening your mesh. Fewer polygons are faster to do physics simulations on.

---

Comment: that's odd. It was doing fine for a while without self collisions. it only started recently.

Comment: I was trying as much as possible not to do self collisions because my computer isn't very powerful

Comment: reduce the mesh density of both your cloth mesh and collision mesh, it will help a lot in that regard.

Comment: And maybe also consider not using cloth sim at all. I don't think your character needs it.

Comment: I want the sleeves to flop around when she moves her arms.